# Cannot display SettingsActivityFragment into a SettingsActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I am basically trying to add SettingsActivityFragment into a SettingsActivity, ending up getting an error like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.a5corp.weather, PID: 3790
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.a5corp.weather/com.a5corp.weather.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
                  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.ensureList(PreferenceFragment.java:420)
                  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.getListView(PreferenceFragment.java:386)
                  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.bindPreferences(PreferenceFragment.java:371)
                  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.onActivityCreated(PreferenceFragment.java:208)
                  at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2362)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1014)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
                  at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6678)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The problem is I have a container inside the activity xml which should do the job, but still it gives me an error. Anyway, Here is SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new SettingsActivityFragment())
                .commit();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

SettingsActivityFragment.java

```
public class SettingsActivityFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    public SettingsActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }

    public void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                       .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                       .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
        String value = (String) o;
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(value);
            if (prefIndex >= 0)
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
        else {
            preference.setSummary(value);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.a5corp.weather.SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.a5corp.weather.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_settings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.a5corp.weather.SettingsActivityFragment">


</RelativeLayout>
```

pref_general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
        android:summary="@string/pref_location_label" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: If you're defining a `<fragment>` element for your `SettingsActivityFragment` in the layout, you don't need to load one dynamically. Anyhoo, the reason you're currently getting that Exception is because the `R.id` you pass to the `add()` method is for the `ViewGroup` that will hold the `Fragment`'s `View`, not one that's inside the `Fragment`'s layout.

Comment: If you remove the `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` piece of code, what happens? Does the Fragment display?

Comment: @cricket_007 , it opens up a blank settings page.

Comment: Edited Question. I had forgot to add the preferences I'm trying to show up.

Comment: `Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class` -  you should search for that error... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941214/strange-error-using-oncreateview-in-preferencefragment-when-calling-addpreferenc